# Why are my e-mails landing in spam in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

I'm sending e-mails from SendGrid. But all the e-mails are landing in the spam box of Gmail accounts, if it contains words like `2vin.com` or `www.2vin.com` in the message body. Other mails are delivering fine.

Answer (score 1):

This link will help you: 
[How to Avoid the SPAM Folder in 10 Easy Steps](http://blog.kissmetrics.com/avoid-the-spam-folder/)

Comment: That's indeed a thorough walkthrough.

Comment: The emails are sent to spam folder only if it contains my website name in the message (www.2vin.com or 2vin.com)  all other mails are working with out those list  is there a way for it so that gmail will not treat them as spam keywords